# Show that $f(x)$ is a minimal polynomial of $T$ if and only if it is a minimal polynomial of $P$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

let $T: M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R) \to M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ be the linear transformation

$T(A) = AP$ for $A, P \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R) $

how to show that $f(x)$ is a minimal polynomial of $T$ if and only if it is a minimal polynomial of $P$?

Answer (score 0):

We have to show that for any polynomial $f$, we have
$$f(T)=0 \ \iff\ f(P)=0\, .$$
As a further **hint**: if $f(x)=\sum_k\alpha_kx^k$, observe that $f(T)$ is $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)\to M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$, with
$$f(T)\,A\ =\ \sum_k\alpha_kAP^k\,.$$